# Como agrupar os dados por semana no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou extraindo uns dados e quero saber alguma forma de agrupar os dados por semana. Estou dando o `SELECT` e ele está trazendo os dados do mês passado e já estou agrupando por dia, mas preciso que seja por semana.

Comment: pode posta sua query para termos uma ideia das suas tabelas e colunas.

Comment: De uma conferida neste link:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php Basicamente usando o operador week com base em um date voce fica sabendo o numero da semana

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi dando o `GROUP BY YEARWEEK(DATA,1)` - esse 1 é o primeiro dia da semana.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Primeiro dia da semana', COUNT(id) AS 'Total'
FROM payments 
WHERE status = 2 AND (created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month) AND CURDATE())
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(created_at, 1)
```